How to configure external source for Percona PMM SQL Server
Description
I started windows_exporter-0.28.1-amd64.exe on Windows SQL Server.
.\windows_exporter-0.28.1-amd64.exe 
     --collectors.enabled "cpu" ts=2024-09-04T08:56:47.079Z 
       caller=exporter.go:216 level=info msg="Running as adm" 
       ts=2024-09-04T08:56:47.085Z caller=exporter.go:223 
       level=info msg="Enabled collectors: cpu" 
       ts=2024-09-04T08:56:47.085Z caller=exporter.go:258 
       level=info msg="Starting windows_exporter" 
       version="(version=0.28.1, branch=HEAD, revision=9febf1e97cc691bb9a29ca6cc69b132e7772acec)" 
       ts=2024-09-04T08:56:47.085Z caller=exporter.go:259 
       level=info msg="Build context" 
       build_context="(go=go1.22.6, platform=windows/amd64, user=runneradmin@fv-az1388-522, date=20240831-17:41:07, tags=unknown)" 
       ts=2024-09-04T08:56:47.086Z caller=tls_config.go:313 
       level=info msg="Listening on" address=[::]:9182 
       ts=2024-09-04T08:56:47.086Z caller=tls_config.go:316 
       level=info msg="TLS is disabled." http2=false address=[::]:9182

Result from http://testsql:9182/metrics
# HELP go_gc_duration_seconds A summary of the wall-time pause (stop-the-world) duration in garbage collection cycles.
# TYPE go_gc_duration_seconds summary
go_gc_duration_seconds{quantile="0"} 0
go_gc_duration_seconds{quantile="0.25"} 0
go_gc_duration_seconds{quantile="0.5"} 0
go_gc_duration_seconds{quantile="0.75"} 0
go_gc_duration_seconds{quantile="1"} 0.000997
go_gc_duration_seconds_sum 0.000997
go_gc_duration_seconds_count 23

I tried over GUI PMM create external service Inventory / Add service / Step 2 of 2 where external service endpoint is my url link. http://testsql:9182/metrics
Service has been created success but I have monitoring status “Failed”. I don’t know where is the problem. In structure generate by windows_exporter or my config.
Thanks for all tips
